# The deployment of my Gatsby CMS is not the one I want, Google maps gatsby plugin

Tags: git, gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

Good evening everyone, Can someone please help me on that ?

I have my Github repo with my Gatsby CMS in it, I have two different branches, master and develop.
To deploy my changes I use netlify that deploys from the master branch. Merges from my develop, I regularly deploy my master branch but it keeps on publishing like nothing happened and stays like my previous commits. Can you tell me where did I mess up with the configuration ?

https://github.com/Hdz/gatsby-starter-netlify-cms

https://fcs.netlify.app/

Second question. I wanted to add "gatsby-source-googlemaps-static"

When I put

```
      resolve: `gatsby-source-googlemaps-static`,
      options: {
        key: `key`,
        center: `47.330209,-1.5219381`,
              },
          },
```

in my gatsby-config.js, I get this error when I try to deploy :

```
6:33:13 PM: error "gatsby-source-googlemaps-static" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:
6:33:13 PM: Request failed with status code 403
6:33:13 PM: 
6:33:13 PM: 
6:33:13 PM:   Error: Request failed with status code 403
6:33:13 PM:   
6:33:13 PM:   - createError.js:16 createError
6:33:13 PM:     [repo]/[axios]/lib/core/createError.js:16:15
6:33:13 PM:   
6:33:13 PM:   - settle.js:17 settle
6:33:13 PM:     [repo]/[axios]/lib/core/settle.js:17:12
6:33:13 PM:   
6:33:13 PM:   - http.js:236 IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd
6:33:13 PM:     [repo]/[axios]/lib/adapters/http.js:236:11
6:33:13 PM:   
6:33:13 PM:   - task_queues.js:84 processTicksAndRejections
6:33:13 PM:     internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21
6:33:13 PM:   
6:33:13 PM: 
6:33:13 PM: not finished source and transform nodes - 0.528s
```

Which I truly don't get. Can anybody find out with me about that too ?

Have a nice day/evening you all.

I tried to follow this : https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-googlemaps-static/

Comment: I went private with the repo because I have one api key on a commit. Sorry about that.